# Vector Limit Proof

Tags: vector-spaces

If $x_n,y_n,x,y$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $x_n\rightarrow x$, $y_n\rightarrow y$ prove that $\langle x_n,y_n\rangle\rightarrow\langle x,y\rangle$

So far I have tried to use Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to get $\lvert\langle x_n,y_n\rangle\rvert \leq\lvert\lvert x_n-x\rvert\rvert \cdot   \lvert\lvert y_n-y\rvert\rvert \rightarrow 0$. From here I am stuck. Can I simply say by definition of limit we then have that $\langle x_n,y_n\rangle\rightarrow\langle x,y\rangle$?

Comment: Try to proof that WLOG you can assume that $x=y=0_m$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant $|\langle x_n-x,y_n-y\rangle|\leq ||x_n-x||\cdot ||y_n-y||$. From there, if you want an $N$-$\varepsilon$ proof, let $\varepsilon>0$ and take $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, where $N_1,N_2$ are the numbers corresponding to the convergence of $x_n$ to $x$ and $y_n$ to $y$ respectively, for $\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. Hence, if $n\geq N$, then $$|\langle x_n-x,y_n-y\rangle|\leq ||x_n-x||\cdot ||y_n-y||<\sqrt{\varepsilon}\cdot\sqrt{\varepsilon}=\varepsilon.$$

If you didn't get there (so I was wrong interpreting you result), you can do the following $$|\langle x_n,y_n\rangle-\langle x,y\rangle|=|\langle x_n,y_n\rangle-\langle x_n,y\rangle+\langle x_n,y\rangle-\langle x,y\rangle|=|\langle x_n,y_n-y\rangle+\langle x_n-x,y\rangle|.$$ From there, use triangle inequality, C-S for each inner product, the fact that $||x_n||$ is bounded (it converges) and an argument similar to the one above with $N$-$\varepsilon$.

Comment: I didn't know how to do a dot product symbol and I mistakenly thought it made no difference.So, you are able to do each norm limit individually and multiply it?